# PHP MySQL Database Images Toggler

Tags: php, mysql, slider

I have built a little uploader that works fine, uploading the images file path to my DB, and storing the image in a folder.
Now I also have made a call that will call only images with the same ID as the Property ID it has assigned.

Where I have trouble is the Image display, I am looking for a simple way to toggle between the images in the database, but even before that, I need to know why the Database call only displays one of the images stored in the DB.

Here is my code so far : 
PHP

```
    if ($id) {
        $query = "SELECT houses.*, gallery_photos.* " .
                "FROM houses LEFT JOIN gallery_photos " .
                "ON $id = gallery_photos.photo_category";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }


// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $images_dir = "houses";
        $photo_caption = $row['photo_caption'];
        $photo_filename = $row['photo_filename'];
        $photo_id = $row['photo_id'];



        }
```

and the display happens withing a larger ECHO command, I will add a little of it so you get the idea :

Within the ECHO

```
 echo "
 <li>
          <div id='imagizer'> <img src='" . $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename ."?id=" . $photo_id . " ' title='$photo_caption'/></div>
          </li>
```

There are many more elements within the li element that work fine, like Title, Price, Summary, etc etc.... But I can simply not accomplish 3 thing here :

1. Getting all the images to display (I only get one, which would be fine if the toggler worked).
2. Making a toggler to display the next image that has the same category_id.
3. Optional (An image slider)

**UPDATE**

This is kind of working, but I get various duplicate entries! It seems that for every picture I get 1 entry on the list. So if 4 pics, 4 entries, if 2, only 2 entries.
    function showShort() {

```
$houses = @mysql_query('SELECT houses.*, gallery_photos.* 
                FROM houses LEFT JOIN gallery_photos 
                ON houses.id = gallery_photos.photo_category');
if (!$houses) {
    die('<p> Error retrieving Propertys from database!<br />' . 'Error: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
}

while ($house = mysql_fetch_array($houses)) {
    $id = $house['id'];
    $title = htmlspecialchars($house['title']);
    $ref = $house['ref'];
    $summary = htmlspecialchars($house['summary']);
//        $content = $house['content'];
    $price = $house['price'];
    $houseorder = $house['houseorder'];
    $pool = $house['pool'];
    $bedrooms = $house['bedrooms'];
    $bathrooms = $house['bathrooms'];
    $aircon = $house['aircon'];
    $basement = $house['basement'];
    $location = $house['location'];
    $floorm = $house['floorm'];
    $aream = $house['aream'];
    $garage = $house['garage'];
    $furbished = $house['furbished'];

    $images_dir = "houses";
    $photo_caption = $house['photo_caption'];
    $photo_filename = $house['photo_filename'];
    $photo_category = $house['photo_category'];
    $photo_id = $house['photo_id'];

    if ($garage == 'Yes') {
        ($garage = "Garage : Yes<br>");
    } elseif ($garage == 'No') {
        ($garage = "");
    }
    if ($pool == 'Yes') {
        ($pool = "Swimming Pool : Yes<br>");
    } elseif ($pool == 'No') {
        ($pool = "");
    }
    if ($aircon == 'Yes') {
        ($aircon = "Air Condition : Yes<br>");
    } elseif ($aircon == 'No') {
        ($aircon = "");
    }
    if ($basement == 'Yes') {
        ($basement = "Basement : Yes<br>");
    } elseif ($basement == 'No') {
        ($basement = "");
    }
    if ($furbished == 'Yes') {
        ($furbished = "Furbished : Yes<br>");
    } elseif ($furbished == 'No') {
        ($furbished = "");
    }

    echo "
    <li>

<div id='summarybox'>
    <div id='titlestyle'> $title </div><br>
 <div id='imagebox'>   </div>
    <div id='refstyle'> Ref. $ref </div>

<div id='details1'> 
    Bedrooms : $bedrooms <br>
    Bathrooms: $bathrooms <br>
    Living Area : $floorm m² <br>
    Plot Area : $aream m² <br>
    Location : $location <br>        

</div>

<div id='details2'>

    $pool
    $aircon 
    $basement 
    $furbished 
    $garage       </div>

<section class='ac-container'>
<div>
    <input id='$id' name='accordion-1' type='checkbox' />
    <label for='$id' >Read More</label>
    <article class='ac-small'>


      <div id='summarystyle'> $summary </div>
      <div id='price'>Price : $price </div><br>

 <div id='imagizer' align='center'>
 <ul id='$id'>
<li><a href='" . $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename . "' rel='lightbox[$photo_category]' title='$photo_caption'><img src='" . $images_dir . "/" .  $photo_filename . "' height='50%' with='50%'/></a></li>
 </ul>


    </article>
 </div>
 </selection>
        <br>
     <div id='admbuttons'><a href='editProperty.php?id=$id' ><button>Edit</button></a>
    <a href='deleteProperty.php?id=$id' onclick='return confirm()'>    <button>Delete</button></a></div>

</div>

                        </li>";
}
}
```

Comment: If you are getting 1 image then display 1 image and use lightbox2 to show all images by just creating a anchor tag in the same li with loop and name the roadmap type same for the anchor tag and the single image  this will show 1 image and when clicked will open lightbox and will load other images with the same category in the lightbox.

This will take less load as images will load when the lightbox opens

Comment: Can you give me a little further info on this? It sounds interesting, but I have never heard of it!? :O

Comment: So I am trying to use Lightbox, but how can I make it load all images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the live example where i have used this idea  just open the below link and click on the thumb image and then slide inside the lightbox.

Inspect the image with firebug and see the anchor tags below the image you will get the logic what i am trying to say and then you can manage it into your code

http://dev.tasolglobal.com/osclass/

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I am trying to accomplish! But somehwere in my Mysql Call and the While loops I am messing up! And I just cant figure out why! I get multiple entries, althought the image slider works right, it displays the images from the $photo_category, in the rel= path, but I get an entry for 1 object listed many times. Let me see if I can upload it to a working portal so you see my problem!

Comment: Here, I have uploaded it to a temporal workspace.
http://www.mein-haus.com/mein-haus/Immobilien.php
Now I have broken something else, that the category separating wont even work...I am so stuck, I am braking more than fixing!

Comment: @Disturbed Budy relax have a cup of tea and then just follow some of my recommendation
1. Your listing looks cool just use my select function and use "For" loop instead of while 
2. Then try putting single image in the listing 
3. Then call select function inside loop to get all images related to that category 
4. Run another FOR loop to create anchor tags
5. Assign unique rel to both the main listing and the tags dynamic according to property 
6. And yes dont forget to include the css and javascript for the lightbox and you may copy them for the source of the example link i have given you

Comment: @Disturbed and yes start in the new php file taking backup of it it will be much faster than finding bugs just follow all above steps with a cool mind it will not take more than 30 to come up with working code 

Please accept my answer if i helped you :)

Comment: Nope, I can't figure out, my brain is saying its enough... I might have to look for another solution, as I am not being able to implement this is my current code.... It must be something so little, and its messing me up so hard... The code I have updated above is my current code, if you are able to fix that with your examples, I would be most grateful, if my code is too broken to be fixed, I will have to give up upon this project...

Comment: @Disturbed Don't give up buddy just mail me your full code related to this page what you have uploaded on the test page i will fix it as here i cant work with your code veerendra2406@gmail.com and atleast accept my answer buddy help me also

Answer (score 1):

your echo statement should be like in for loop

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $images_dir = "houses";
        $photo_caption = $row['photo_caption'];
        $photo_filename = $row['photo_filename'];
        $photo_id = $row['photo_id'];
 echo "
 <li>
     <div id='imagizer'> <img src='" . $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename ."' id=" . $photo_id . "  title='$photo_caption'/></div>
 </li>

    }
```

id and src should have some space to print in echo.

please add above code in you for loop sure it will work for you.

Comment: Explain this a little further please, I do not see any difference to my actual code, apart of the fact that you have removed the ?= for the Photo_ID measure! Thanks for the reply! :D

Comment: Pls use my updated code will sure work for you. pls dont forget to acpt my answer,if it is useful toyou

Comment: I did, it still does only display one image at the time!

Comment: pls check your while loop is it executing multiple times also check your view source might be with design issue will overwrite another images. is your `<li>` repeat multiple times ?

Answer (score 0):

The main thumb single image

```
<a href="url of the first image"  rel="lightbox['unique name for a particular bunch of image']><img src="url of the first image" /></a>
```

Just fire a query and get all the image url only for the particular category  and run a loop for the urls to create anchor tags with rel

```
for($b=1;$b<$thumb_url;$b++)
 {
 echo = '<a href="here should be the image urls" rel="lightbox['a unique name or could be a category id to make it unique if you are showing multiple category on the same page']"></a>';
 }
```

These image url are in the href so will not load on page load and when the lightbox will be triggered on the click of the first image it will load all the images with a particular unique string in the rel="lightbox[]"  and will show next and previous link to show images like slider

You can use "cat_" then the unique id of a particular category to make unique the rel of those particular images.

I have tried it and it works

UPDATE 
What you need to do is do not loop the li but just place the first image in the li inside the img tag and the unique rel and then after the li you have to run the loop for the rest of the category images and create anchor tag with image url in the href and rel similar to the first image

Do not forget to include the js and css for the light box

```
<div id='imagizer' align='center'>
<ul id='$id'>
   <li><a href='" . $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename . "' rel='lightbox[$photo_category]' title='$photo_caption'><img src='" . $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename . "' height='50%' with='50%'/></a></li>
</ul>
```

//Put your loop here to make the anchor tags and keep the url in the href only with the rel corresponding to the first image so they will be treated as a bunch by lightbox

Create a common select function and try query with it and then use for loop on the result associative array it will be less confusion and neat code

### Execute Select Query

```
function select ($sql="", $fetch = "mysql_fetch_assoc")
    {
        global $conn;
        $results = @mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if(!$results) {
            echo mysql_errno()." : ". mysql_error();    
        }
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $fetch($results))
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        mysql_free_result($results);
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your code but I am having trouble!
I have this for the loop : $thumb_url = $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename;
        }
        for ($b = 1; $b < $thumb_url; $b++) {
            echo "<a href='" . $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename . "' rel='lightbox[$photo_category]'> </a>";
        }
and this in the echo :  <li>

                 <a href='" . $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename . "' rel='lightbox[$photo_category]' title='$photo_caption'><img src='" . $images_dir . "/" . $photo_filename . "' height='50%' with='50%'/></a>
                     
              </li>

Comment: It loads the first image perfectly fine, but I can not toggle between the other images! I am not even sure they are being pulled into the Array tbh!

Comment: May you help a little more? :P

Comment: Its too late dude will surely help you next morning

Comment: I have updated the post with the full code that I am using to call against the DB. I fear that the double "while" loop may be casuing trouble here. Maybe you see the mistake, I simply dont find it! :(

Comment: @Disturbed Check my updated answer i can share you the example url but not here

Comment: Hey buddy, I have just updated my code a little, I have cleaned it. May you have a look at it and then help me figure out what the heck I am missing? :) Thanks alot for all your time!

Comment: @Disturbed Sorry but i can't get your code what you wanna do then i also i am posting another answer to make you understand what exactly i mean

Comment: I am trying to build in another function, I already had the main function to Display the object information, and decided to add an image slider afterwards... This is why my function seems so messy right now. What I am trying to archieve is a function that will call all the details of the house object (Title price etc etc) that is easy, as its just 1 parameter per $row, but now I am trying to take the lightbox to do an imageslider of the house pictures, I want 1 main picture to be displayed, and the others to be slided. I hope I was able to explain myself a little better!Thanks again